# Database with several primary keys attached to a list

Tags: database

I have a database that has two primary keys that represent two representative and unique items for each item of the table.

This pair of values in the table is attached to a list of identifiers of another table. That table looks more or less like this:

[image]

I have te "Electro" database that has two primary keys and each pair of them is attached to a list of images. But I can't insert on database the same pair of PK (primary key) with different image id.

I was thinking on storing a list of strings with each identifiers, but that solution is not good.

How can I attach a pair of "id", "profile_id" to several image ids without putting the image id as a primary key? Is there any way without making the image ID a primary key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying you want more than one row in Images to be linked to a single Electro.  If so then you need to add two columns to images:
electroId  and electro_profileId and make them a foreign key to the electro table.   Even better add a single primary key column to the Electro table and use that as the target for a foreign key column in images.

Comment: Hello @billpennock. Yes, what you say is what I need. I think the second one doesn't allow me to add more than an image id to my profile_id, isn't it?

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as "answered".  I need the reputation points :)

Comment: I'm still thinking if this is the most suitable solution for me... When I know I will mark it. :)